# How would I account for negative values in Python?

Tags: python, validation, int, startswith

I am trying to see if a string (it has to be a string) is a number.

So far I am using `isdigit()` but apparently `isdigit` does not account for negative numbers.

If I do `isdigit(a)` and `a = -1` I get False.

If I do `isdigit(a)` and `a = 1` I get True.

So far I have,

```
def rotationKeyValidated(rotationKeyStr):
    if rotationKeyStr.startswith('-') and rotationKeyStr[1:].isdigit():
        int(rotationKeyStr)
    return rotationKeyStr.isdigit()
```

I am trying to see if it starts with a negative sign, and the rest is a digit then well.. I don't know because I don't want to use multiple return statements.

Comment: why you simply cant use `type(n) == int`

Comment: @Hackaholic - Because `rotationKeyStr` is a string object.  Also, you should be doing `isinstance(n, int)` to test the type of `n`.  `type(n) == int` does not regard inheritance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [`try/except` block](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) and attempt to convert the string into an integer:

```
def rotationKeyValidated(rotationKeyStr):
    try:
        int(rotationKeyStr)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

This style of coding embraces Python's [EAFP principle](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) and is preferred by most Python programmers.  It is also quite robust, handling any string that can be converted into an `int`.

---

Since your assignment requires only one return-statement, you can add an `else:` block and a flag:

```
def rotationKeyValidated(rotationKeyStr):
    try:
        int(rotationKeyStr)
    except ValueError:
        flag = False
    else:
        flag = True
   return flag
```

The `else:` block will only be executed if the `try:` block executes without raising an error.

---

Well, since you *must* use `str.isdigit`, you could always do something like this:

```
def rotationKeyValidated(rotationKeyStr):
    if rotationKeyStr.startswith('-'):
        rotationKeyStr = rotationKeyStr[1:]
    return rotationKeyStr.isdigit()
```

The if-statement checks if the string starts with `-` and removes that character if so.  After that, we can safely return the result of `str.isdigit`.

Comment: That would mean if I were to put -5 I would get 5. The end result has to be negative if you input a negative number. I think I'm just going to explain to my teachers why I didn't use it. Last question, in another part of my program I have to remove \n from a string... I can do this with rstrip()... But how would I put them back?

Comment: No, `rotationKeyStr[1:]` creates a new string and uses that.  It does not mutate (alter) the string you pass in (strings are immutable in Python).  As for `str.rstrip`, you would need to keep track of how many newlines you removed from the end of the string.  You could do something like `len(msytr) - len(mystr.rstrip('\n'))`.